# Power-utility function for calculating Certainty equivalent

Tags: equities, finance, asset-pricing, expected-return, utility-theory

**I have a question regarding how i should calculate 3.2-3.4, currently studying for an exam. What i don't get is how to acctually derive the certainty equivalent from the expected utility of gross returns.
3.1: is that the expected return (1.075, 7.5%) = risk premium since the risk-free rate = 0.**

[image: 3.1]

**3.2: As to my understanding the expected utility of gross returns should be calculated in this way:
0.5*ln(80/100) + 0.5*ln(100/135) = 1.0384. But how do i proceed from here? Since i need to use the power utility function.**

[image: 3.2]

**I will skip 3.3 since it just ask what if A=8**

**3.4: What is a possible solution for this?**

[image: 3.4]

**Thanks in advance!**